# Stata Weighted Least Squares Regression

Tags: stata

I realize this may be a novice question, but I'm still a beginner with Stata.  I have a dataset that I'm trying to run a weighted least squares regression on, and I've installed the wls0 package.  However, when I try to run my regression, I get a strange error:

option wvars() required
r(198);

This doesn't happen when I try to run a regression for an example dataset used in a wls0 tutorial.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: do you have a variable in the `wvars` parameter of your regression?  :)  try following [this example](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/ado/analysis/wls0.htm)..

Comment: That's an option, not a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`wls0` is from  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/ado/analysis/ and requires such an option. So this is expected and in no sense surprising.